# cant login using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start

Tags: c#, .net

i am tying to login using  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore","username@gmail.com","password","http://www.gmail.com");

    }
```

but visual studio gives me these 2 errors: Error    1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(string, string, System.Security.SecureString, string)' has some invalid arguments    C:\Documents and Settings\Omair\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\Form1.cs 21  13  WindowsFormsApplication3

and

Error   2   Argument '3': cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Security.SecureString'    C:\Documents and Settings\Omair\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\Form1.cs 21  80  WindowsFormsApplication3

note: i am brand new to c# and reletively new to the world of programming
sorry for my english

Comment: Where do you want to login? In GMail? Using `Process.Start` you are very far from achieving this objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is not going to work.  GMail is not a regular Windows program, the kind that you can start with Process.Start().  It is coded in Javascript and runs in your browser.  The login procedure is handled by Javascript.

You'll need a browser plug-in to tinker with GMail.  A popular one that works on Firefox is Greasemonkey.  Lots of GMail hacks in this [google query](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=greasemonkey+gmail+scripts&aq=0&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=greasemonkey+gmail+&gs_rfai=C6M9Yrpf2S8nvCY36M-6XgbcCAAAAqgQFT9CiHNE&fp=6f78d0ffc1b1e58c).

Answer (score 0):

Secure string is a "Special" type of string in the .net framework.  It's encrypted.

Here is how to convert a string to a secure string:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/netfxbcl/thread/ada5def5-0d80-43d6-ab5d-9fb1934e6556

Another example:
http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/03/04/2873.aspx

This being said, I don't think this will achieve what you want it to.  The username and password option on process start is for starting the application (IE in your case) and running it under a different account.

MSDN [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx)
MSDN [Process Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx)

Comment: then how to login to gmail progamatically? can you point to an example?
note:an ''easy for biggener'' example would be nice